# Call URL with querystring and recieve return from this page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a button on my user.php page. This button must call action.php?name=john&id=10 onclick without refresh the page.

The page action.php should proccess this querystring data (name=john & id=10), perform some action and send an message back..

user.php example:

```
<button onclick="callAction()">Do it!</button>

function callAction() {
    //call action.php?name=john&id=10
}

action.php example:

<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

if(id == 10) {
   //send user.php some successful text
} else {
   //send user.php some error text
}
```

?>

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Errr...shouldn't `action.php/name=john` be `action.php?name=john`?

Comment: Yes. Just a typing mistake! Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can make the ajax call like:

```
$.get('action.php?name=john&id=123', function (data) {
    console.log('response: ', data);
});
```

Here is the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Downvoted because this answer assumes OP is using jQuery.

Comment: @PhillipChan Well I didn't say "Since you are using jQuery", I just gave a viable option to use jQuery to do it easily, but whatever dude. OP if you want to do it without jQuery, check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp